# How can i use/integrate Passbook/Wallet/PassKit for Event Invitation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, passbook, wallet

We are developing an application which has events & conferences schedule, Each invitee has to carry some an invitation card to enter an event or conference, Can we create a Pass & add it to Passbook/Wallet app, so that invitee doesn't need to carry physical invitation card? FYI: For Invitation user doesn't need to pay any amount.

As Apple is very strict about usage of Passbook/Wallet I seek guidance on it.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: You will have no problem, as we have hundreds of clients doing exactly that.  If you wish to be certain then the Apple developer forum is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in my that there is no difference between traditional (paper) pass and electronic, since all carry the same information (barcode)

The only difference that you can place in digital pass that you can create different layers of logic, such as, let's say at 14:00 there is a coffeebreak, change image to 'coffee break time' and notify all users so, monitor users, who installed pass. There are plenty of opportunities.

Refering back to your question. Apple strictly suggests that you create 1 passtype id for 1 organization, means 99$/year per company or developer account, however they don't strictly monitor it (personal experience)

Hope this helps